# Listen for a click outside directive used multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive which has a popup-menu inside itself, which should be shown when i click on a button inside my directive and it should be closed whenever i click outside the directive.

I use the directive for multiple items in a list so there will always be multiple of this directive on the page.

Right now i have some code which is listening for a click on the document. I have moved this code to my controller since it gets evaluated x times according to the number of directives on the page.

Is there something smart i can do to keep all the code inside the directive??

```
// BOTTOM OF MY CONTROLLER //

// function to be called when clicking outside the directive/menu
onDocumentClick = function(event){
// if not clicked on an .popup-btn then remove all classnames from popup-menu
activeNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-menu active");
if(activeNodes.length >= 1){
    clicked_el = angular.element(event.target);
    if(!/^popup-btn|popup-menu/.test(clicked_el[0].className)){
        for (var i = 0; i < activeNodes.length; i++){
            activeNodes[i].className = "popup-menu";
            console.log(activeNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
};

$document.on('click', onDocumentClick);
}]);

// END OF CONTROLLER //

//Directive
mealplan.directive('recipe', ['$document', function($document) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        item: '=recipe' 
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // toggle the recipe menu
        scope.toggleMenu = function() {
            console.log("toggle menu");
            // loop throug all menus and reset their class names
            activeNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-menu active");
            if(activeNodes.length >= 1){
                for (var i = 0; i < activeNodes.length; i++){
                    activeNodes[i].className = "popup-menu";
                    console.log(activeNodes[i]);
                }
            }
            // set the current 
            current = elem[0].getElementsByClassName("popup-menu")[0];
            current.className = "popup-menu active";
            console.log(current);
        };

        // initializes the states
        scope.init = function() {
            //scope.currentMenu = null;
        };

        scope.init();

    },
    templateUrl: 's/recipes/js/popupMenu-directive.html'
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you could use `.off` to remove the binding if already present and then set the `.on` event.

```
$document.off('click.some-namespace');
$document.on('click.some-namespace', function() { ... });
```

Use a namespace for your event to leave any other click events untouched. This way the event should be bound a single time, no matter the number of times the directive is used.

Comment: Indeed it is not very elegant, but if it works. I will give it a try when i get home tonight and if it fits my needs you will get the answer.

Comment: The jqLite implementation in AngularJS does not support namespaces: on() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData - but your method works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Code that you execute in your directive before returning the options object will be executed only once.

From the [Angular-UI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives):

```
myApp.directive('uiJq', function InjectingFunction(){

    // === InjectingFunction === //
    // Logic is executed 0 or 1 times per app (depending on if directive is used).
    // Useful for bootstrap and global configuration
    // Do the binding here
    return {
        compile: function CompilingFunction($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {

            // Logic is executed once (1) for every instance of ui-jq

            return function LinkingFunction($scope, $linkElement, $linkAttributes) {
                // Logic is executed once (1) for every RENDERED instance.
            };
        }
    };
})
```

You can bind your event handler after the declaration of the directive, and it will be executed only once.

Comment: This also gave me a better understanding of how the directives are build.